# QT View/Model Login dialog

Tags: python, pyqt

So I am trying to build a login dialog for my application using qt/python.

I got confused by QT's view/model architecture. QT provides models and view for tables, lists etc., but how do I go about implementing a login dialog using this architecture?

I use a ui file that I created with QtDesigner.

Should I create a user model that interfaces with the DB and retrieves user data, handling the login process, and return this result to the view? (view and controller combined, as per QT's terminology)

I would like to use the same architecture throughout the application, but I got confused with this one. Do I even need a model for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models are for binding data to view. You can create list model with user/password fields and use `QWidgetMapper` to bind it to two `QLineEdits` but there's no much use in it since there's no much data and no complicated interactions.